# skip multiple values in foreach loop

Tags: c#, .net, linq, foreach, skip

I have following string array, and I'm getting its as string in `foreach` loop

```
string[] words = ...

foreach (String W in words.Skip(1))
{
      ...
}
```

I can skip first value but How can I skip 1st value and last value both ?

Comment: `StartsWIth / EndsWith` would be my first choice..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
foreach (string w in words.Skip(1).Take(words.length-2))
{
    ...
}
```

Probably best to put some tests before this to ensure there are enough words!

Answer (score 13):

This is an array right...

```
for (int i = 1; i < words.Length - 1; i++)
{
    string W = words[i];
    //...
}
```

Comment: LOL, finally one normal answer +1

Comment: While I agree this should be the best answer, I think he was asking how to do this on linq. Anyway, here goes my upvote

Comment: `foreach` was mentioned in the question title, but as we're not going over "each" I thought I'd just ignore that, now you mention it I see the linq tag.

Comment: @Gonzalo.- Correct, but that's LINQ abuse. Also all the LINQ answers use the non LINQ `Length` property, so it's interesting how they will perform on a real LINQ enumerable that has no `Count` property - will execute it 3 times.

Comment: @C.Evenhuis What's a purpose to use `foreach` for arrays or Lists? They are ordered and have known size. Using a `for` loop will even give you an index which will allow accessing next or previous element etc.

Answer (score 6):

Use this

```
words.Skip(1).Take(words.Length-2)
```

It is -2 so you don't count the one you've skipped, plus the one you want to skip from the end

Answer (score 1):

```
int count = 0;
string[] words = { };

foreach (string w in words)
{
      if(count == 0 || count == (words.Length - 1)){
      continue;
      }
      //Your code goes here
      count++;
}
```

This should work for you if you must use a foreach loop.

Comment: You should check for `words.Length - 1`

Answer (score 1):

You can use [ArraySegment](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1hsbd92d.aspx)

```
var clipped = new ArraySegment<String>(words, 1, words.Length-2);

foreach (String W in clipped)
{
      ...
}
```